# Angular passed data from service to component not working with ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello im using angular to make a video game page, when you click a specific title it sends the id to make a api call with the specific id. I can get the data into the  selected-games component where i want to use it but when i use ngFor it shows nothing. no errors and no data.

home component where the you can select the specific  video game. I added the settimeout and routing to this ts file thinking if i could delay the routing until the array in selected-game-component loaded but it didnt work.

```
constructor( private getGame: SelectedGameComponent, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }



  sendId(id: any){
  // this.gamesService.functionGetGameById(id);
     this.getGame.test(id);

     setTimeout( () => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('game')
     }, 5000)
  }
}
```

The selected game component where im trying to map the data in the html file

```
game: any = [];
constructor(private getGames: FetchingVideoGamesService) { }

 test(id: any){
    this.getGames.functionGetGameById(id).subscribe(response =>{
      this.game = response;
      console.log(this.game)
    })
  }
}
```

and the fetch service

```
 functionGetGameById(id: any){
    return this.http.get<any>('https://api.rawg.io/api/games/'+id+'?key=keyremovedforpost'
      )
      .pipe(map(response =>{
        const gameArray: any = [];
        gameArray.push(response)
        console.log(gameArray, 'response from service')
        return gameArray[0]
      }))

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting a child component into the parent component... you might as well use a service for that.

I suggest the following approach, which is the recommended one, a reactive approach, let the parent call `functionGetGameById()` from the service, once the parent gets the data back, then proceeds to send it to his child.

**parent**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  games$!: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private getGames: FetchingVideoGamesService) { }
  
  callTheService(id: string): void {
    this.games$ = this.getGames.functionGetGameById(id);
  }
}
```

**parent html**

```html
...
<your-child-component [theGames]="games$ | async">
</your-child-component>
```

**child**

```js
...
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() theGames!: any[];
}
```

**child html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let game of theGames">
 {{ game }}
</div>
```

With this, you keep one-way communication between your components (top to bottom), the parent component becomes a smart component, the one that knows about the logic business, while your child component becomes a dumb component, it only does a very specific thing and that's it, if the child needs to send back some data to the parent, use an `Ouput` event emitter

Comment: So i was trying something similar when you commeneted, except im using a service and they are not really parent/child components so i dont think i can use event listeners? all the logic is held in the service and both components are tapping into that service. its passing it up to the service but on passing it down to  ngOnit it reads Error trying to diff 'Grand Theft Auto V'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed